# How to make unread button in messaging application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, html

I'm working on a div that are displaying messages (like emails) from database on iOS (UIwebview)application
Like this:

```
<div>
%title%
%message%
</div>
```

All i want to do is that notify user some way of unread messages, just like in email applications on iOS.

how can i programmatically put some kind of symbols that only shows with unread messages and once user click on it it disappear it self from that div.

Comment: Can (or does) your database store information as to whether a message has been read or not? And is it possible to manipulate the html for each item in the uiwebview (access to the style or class attributes to apply CSS styling)

Comment: is your webview load from an host URL or iOS App's local bundle ?

Comment: NickSlash:No current database is not storing reading information from user, But we can always add - Thanks

Comment: Cullen SUN : messages loads from local sqlite